# Retrieve data column wise in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a problem where I need to display subject names (ex- english, science ....)  of student as columns and under each subject their respective marks. I query a database and get these values as rows in dataset not as columns. How should I query the database?

My query result

```
student name | marks  | Subectname
------------------------------------
raghuram        78         english
raghuram        34         physics
raghuram        76         chemistry

 ................              ...         ..........
```

Required result in report

```
studentname | english | Maths | physics | ......
----------------------------------------------------
raghuram        78       66        32
```

Here's my query

```
SELECT
    st.FirstName + ' ' + st.LastName as StudentName,
    s.Subject_Name, se.Mark 
FROM
    dbo.FEE_STUDENT_EXAM se
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.FEE_STUDENT_GRADE sg ON sg.Student_ID=se.Student_ID
INNER JOIN 
    FEE_STUDENT st ON st.Student_ID=sg.Student_ID
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.EMP_SUBJECT s ON s.SubjectID=se.Subject_ID
WHERE
    sg.Grade_ID = @GradeId 
    AND sg.Division_ID = @DivId 
    AND se.Subject_ID IN (SELECT d.SubjectId 
                          FROM dbo.FEE_STUDENT_EXAM_SCHEDULED d 
                          INNER JOIN dbo.FEE_STUDENT_EXAM_SCHEDULEH h ON h.ExamScheduleID = d.ExamScheduleID 
                          WHERE h.Grade_Id = @GradeId AND h.Division_ID = @DivId 
                            AND YEAR(CAST(d.TestDate AS DATETIME)) = @Year
                            AND MONTH(CAST(d.TestDate AS DATETIME)) = @Month)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `GROUP BY` to your query and `max(case...)` for each subject you need:

```
    Select st.FirstName+' '+st.LastName as
           StudentName,

          max(case when s.Subject_Name = 'english' then se.Mark else 0 end) as english,     
          max(case when s.Subject_Name = 'Maths' then se.Mark else 0 end) as Maths,
          max(case when s.Subject_Name = 'physics' then se.Mark else 0 end) as physics,
.........

     from   dbo.FEE_STUDENT_EXAM se
                   inner join dbo.FEE_STUDENT_GRADE sg on sg.Student_ID=se.Student_ID
                   inner join FEE_STUDENT st on st.Student_ID=sg.Student_ID
                   inner join dbo.EMP_SUBJECT s on s.SubjectID=se.Subject_ID
                   where sg.Grade_ID=@GradeId and sg.Division_ID=@DivId and
                   se.Subject_ID in(Select  d.SubjectId from dbo.FEE_STUDENT_EXAM_SCHEDULED d inner join 
                   dbo.FEE_STUDENT_EXAM_SCHEDULEH h on h.ExamScheduleID=d.ExamScheduleID where 
                   h.Grade_Id=@GradeId and h.Division_ID=@DivId and year(cast (d.TestDate as datetime))=@Year
                   and month(cast (d.TestDate as datetime))=@Month)

               Group by se.Student_ID
```

Comment: here we dont know what all subjects are present.It may vary with higher classes..

Comment: You can also use [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) in your query but it also requires a fixed column list.

Comment: Or also you can make your query dynamically. [Here you can find an example.](http://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2007/09/14/pivots-with-dynamic-columns-in-sql-server-2005/)